# Cannot align static fields for Details page in Bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, metronic

I want to use label as used "Static Control" label on [that](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/form_controls.html) page. However, although I use the same Bootstrap version, I cannot aligned my form controls like that (I want the label is right float, data fields is left float -side by side - and there is a ":" sign between them. Howwver, the result is as shown on the image below. Could you please have a look at my code and inform what is wrong?

**The code on that page:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Static Control</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="form-control-static"> email@example.com </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The code I use on my Razor page:**

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" }):
     <div class="col-md-9">
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control-static" })
     </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" }):
     <div class="col-md-9">
         @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control-static" })
     </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: `DisplayFor()` does not accept html attributes (it does not even output a `<p>` element - just text) - `<p class="form-control-static">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</p>`

Comment: What should I do in razor instead of DisplayFor() to solve this problem?

Comment: Of course that should be strongly typed so that I can use model.Name, etc...

Comment: I tried but did not make any sense (the texts just went to below as 1 px). Any other idea?

Comment: As far as I see the problem seems to be related to other elements or classes as "col-md-9", etc. Because I see the same result when I use **<p class="form-control-static"> email@example.com </p>**.

Comment: Using the code in my previous comments will produce the identical html to what you have shown in your first snippet.

Comment: Then you need to check/compare the css for the elements to find the differences

Comment: I inspected using Firebug and see that **"col-md-9"** is out of **"form-group"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for all of your helps...

```
<style>
    .col-sm-3 .control-label {
        float: right !important;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    /*Add colon ( : ) to the end of labels */
    .col-sm-3 > label:after {
        content: " :";
    }
</style>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "control-label" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Surname)
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: This is hacky, I would suggest figuring out why the bootstrap classes don't work, probably because you don't have the form groups inside a bootstrap form

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements which equal 100% width plus the colon, so it pushes the value down a line. You'll need to just code the label instead of using an HtmlHelper to add the colon. Change it to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-3 control-label">@Model.Name:</label>
   <div class="col-md-9">
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control-static" })
   </div>
</div>
```